# How to filter only dates in excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a column that has dates in some cells, also string values in several cells in the same column, How I should filter only the dates.

**Current output:**

```
F  Group: 1
Result Date/Time
22-07-2020  10:36:00
Comments 29-07-2020  09:00:00
29-07-2020  14:22:00
Set Comments
```

**Expected output:**

```
22-07-2020  10:36:00
29-07-2020  09:00:00
29-07-2020  14:22:00
```

looking for your help

Comment: They all are just string? Or there are true date?

Comment: @Harun24HR right now the format is in custom

Comment: Give a try on my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Excel365` you can try

```
=FILTER(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A6," ","</s><s>",1)&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"),ISNUMBER(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2:A6," ","</s><s>",1)&"</s></t>","//s[last()]")))
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the output as "43977.35764"

Comment: You need to format resulting cells as date like `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`.

Comment: @LearnwithKumaran Or use `TEXT()` function to display result as your desired date time format.